# debugging with browserify: calling functions and vars in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, console, browserify

Is it possible to call functions while running node modules using browserify? When I try calling functions or vars in the browser console it throws an Uncaught ReferenceError error. However, when I run the code without the node modules my calls are executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug with chrome devtools and breakpoints. Breakpoint will stop code execution temporarily and the variables & functions will be in scope. You won't get uncaught reference error.

When the code has stopped at the place you wanted, now hit the console and check.